# android не выводить иконку приложения после установки

Tags: android, установка

Как после установки своего приложения не выводить иконку приложения на рабочий стол?

Так же хотелось, чтобы иконка не появлялась и в списке всех приложений и в меню настройки/приложения. Возможно ли такое сделать, и если возможно подскажите куда смотреть?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы иконка не появлялась в меню и на рабочем столе, удалите все `intent-filter` типа

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Если приложение не будет появляться в списке установленных приложений в настройках, значит его невозможно будет удалить. Это невозможно. Если бы было возможно, это была бы большая очевидная дыра в безопасности.

Comment: если их убрать возможно ли будет после установки приложения автоматически запустить сервис?

Answer (score 3):

Так вы никак не скроете, то, что устанавливается - находится в приложениях.
В целях безопасности, от таких как вы и сделали, чтобы была установка и уведомления об установке.